# Unable to change folder ownership using Chown in docker file

Tags: linux, docker, chown

I'm unable to change ownership of a folder when running `chown` in the dockerfile. Currently /app/Data is owned by `root` and I'm trying to give ownership to `moduleuser`.

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore Project/Magic.csproj --configfile ./NuGet.Config
RUN dotnet publish Project/Magic.csproj -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime-stretch-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/Magic/out ./

RUN mkdir /sqlite
RUN chmod 777 /sqlite
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash moduleuser
RUN chown -R moduleuser:moduleuser /app/Data
USER moduleuser

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Magic.dll"]
```

When building the image, No error is thrown by `RUN chown -R moduleuser:moduleuser /app/Data`.

`Step 12/14 : RUN chown -R moduleuser:moduleuser /app/Data
 ---> Running in f02802d1bb5a
Removing intermediate container f02802d1bb5a
 ---> 1558b0aaf823
Step 13/14 : USER moduleuser`

When I check the ownership of /app/Data, it still shows `root`.

`moduleuser@cdcc6f8b78bc:/app/Data$ ls -ld
 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 29 00:06 .`

if I go inside the container and run `chown -R moduleuser:moduleuser /app/Data`, this does work and the ownership is switched to `moduleuser` but for some reason it's not working through the dockerfile.

What am I missing here?

Comment: you are showing us permissions of `.` ? what are permissions of other files in `/app/Data`?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Post the text itself. What if you would run `chown -vR` with verbose?

Comment: @rok the `.` in this case is `/app/Data` and the files in there currently shows `root` as owner.

Comment: @KamilCuk I ran `-vR` and it shows : `changed ownership of '/app/Data' from root:root to moduleuser:moduleuser`

Comment: How are you actually running the container?

Answer (score 0):

is /app/Data the mount point of a fat32 partition? In such a case it wont work, because fat32 doesn't implement ownership.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case because if I go inside the container and run `chown -R moduleuser:moduleuser /app/Data`, this does work and the ownership is switched to `moduleuser` but for some reason it's not working through the dockerfile.